# Get lines between two patterns

Tags: shell, sed, ksh

I'm using `ksh` shell and below is the sample text in a file

```
AAA
ccc
ddd
eee
XXX
AAA
lll
mmm
eee
YYY
```

from the above text, I want to print only the line between `AAA` and `XXX` and final output will be like

```
AAA
ccc
ddd
eee
XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `sed` for a task like that. It supports a syntax like from lines matching `AAA` print everything up to and including a line matching `XXX`.

Alas your input is a bit ill-formed because the starting pattern `AAA` occurs twice without a matching `XXX` for the second `AAA`. sed default behavior is to match from the second `AAA` until the last line in the input when the `XXX` is not found after the second `AAA`. The details are explained in the last section of the [sed faq](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq3_006.html).

But there is also a solution how to match only the first block: this code is directly taken from the FAQ and adopted to your question:

```
sed -n '/AAA/{:a; N;/XXX/! b a; p;} yourfile.txt'
```

- `/AAA/` and `/XXX/` are sed expression to match your start and end line
- `/AAA/{:a;N;/XXX/! ba;  ... }` is a loop: from a line matching `AAA` it it

  - executes a `N` command reading the next line
  - if the line does not match `/XXX/!` (notice the `!` which negates the match) it branches back (`b`) to label `a` reading the next line.
  - only when the line matches `XXX` we leave the branch loop and print `p` the lines

---

If your input has always a matching `XXX` for every `AAA` and those blocks are not nested, the command is much more intuitive:

```
sed -n '/AAA/,/XXX/ p' yourfile.txt
```